# how to prove $f$ is a linear function?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f\in L^2[0,1]$ be such taht $\int_0^1f(x)g(x)dx=0$, for all continous functions $g$ with the property that $$\int_0^1g(x)dx=\int_0^1xg(x)dx=0$$. 
Prove that $f$ is a linear function with the form $''ax+b''$ such that $f(x)=ax+b;a\in[0,1]$

Comment: $g(x)$ must be orthogonal to the constant function and the function $x$. This leaves a linear combination of these two for $f(x)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint/sketch:** One idea would be to express $f$ in a convenient orthogonal basis of $L_2([0,1])$, e.g. the [shifted Legendre polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials#Shifted_Legendre_polynomials) (?), each of them (except for those of degree at most $1$) satisfying the hypothesis of "$g$". By using orthogonality and continuity, this shows that all coefficients of $f$ except the first two in this basis are $0$, i.e. that $f$ must be affine.